# Difficulty with zeros from 2D FFTW

Tags: c, fftw

I have a real matrix represented by the structure `double input[N][M]` where I want to take a 1D FT for each column j = 0..M along the N direction. My attempt at this is as follows:

```
#include <fftw3.h>
#include <math.h>

#define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846264338327

int main(void)
{
    int N = 16; int M = 2;

    double input[N][M];             // input data
    double *in = (double *) input;

    fftw_complex output[N][M];      // output data
    fftw_complex *out = (fftw_complex *) output;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; ++j)
        {
            double x = (double) i / (double) N;
            input[i][j] = sin(2*(j+1) * M_PI * x);
            fprintf (stderr, "input[%d][%d] = %.9f, ", i, j, input[i][j]);
        }
        fprintf (stderr, "\n");
    }
    fprintf (stderr, "\n");

    // setup plans
    int rank = 1; int howmany = M;
    int istride = M; int ostride = M; int idist = 1; int odist = 1;

    fftw_plan fp = fftw_plan_many_dft_r2c(rank, &N, howmany,
                                          in, NULL, istride, idist,
                                          out, NULL, ostride, odist,
                                          FFTW_MEASURE);


    // take the forward transform
    fftw_execute(fp); fprintf (stderr, "FFT complete\n");

    for (int j = 0; j < M; ++j)
        for (int i = 0; i < N/2; ++i)
            fprintf (stderr, "OUT[%3d] = (%.4f + %.4fi)\n",
                    i, output[i][j][0], output[i][j][1]);

    fprintf (stderr, "\n");

    fftw_destroy_plan(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

which I'm compiling with `gcc fft.c -std=c99 -g -lfftw3 -lm`. However the code doesn't appear to be working: FT output is all zeros (see [here](http://pastebin.com/Km2nZx6H))

Documentation for the function is [here](http://www.fftw.org/doc/Advanced-Real_002ddata-DFTs.html#Advanced-Real_002ddata-DFTs).

**EDIT**: update, so it only seems to work for FFTW_ESTIMATE and not any of the [other flags](http://www.fftw.org/doc/Planner-Flags.html#Planner-Flags). Any idea why this might be?

Comment: Mm the valgrind output is confusing: http://pastebin.com/4jYw5c3G? Or should I use gdb? (relatively new to this!)

Comment: If you check the Valgrind output, you see it prints the stack-trace, with the bottom of the stack being line 32 in the file `fftw.c`. Start by examining this line, its context and its variables.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the FFTW library, but to me the declaration `int n[] = {N}` looks suspicious too. This will create an array containing only a single entry. Accessing (reading or writing) beyond this single entry is undefined behavior.

Comment: I think that's OK according to the docs (it knows about the length from `rank`), but to be sure I can replace it with &N which has equivalent behaviour

Comment: I'm not sure fftw_complex output[N][M]; is the best way to do this. Try using fftw_malloc(). Its made specifically to work with FFTW.

Comment: @tir38 agreed! This was just a quick test, but in actual code I will indeed use `fftw_malloc()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah cracked it! From the [Planner Flags page](http://www.fftw.org/doc/Planner-Flags.html#Planner-Flags):

> Important: the planner overwrites the input array during planning
>   unless a saved plan (see Wisdom) is available for that problem, so you
>   should initialize your input data after creating the plan. The only
>   exceptions to this are the FFTW_ESTIMATE and FFTW_WISDOM_ONLY flags,
>   as mentioned below.

So it was setting up the plan and overwriting the input: easy solution is to move plan creation before initialisation of data array.

Working example code (which FTs forward, then back) [here](http://pastebin.com/kCY7wrRm).

Answer (score 0):

The culprit is probably this declaration:

```
double *in = (double *) in;
```

This declares `in` as a pointer to a `double` (or an array of doubles). You then make it point to itself, but it doesn't point anywhere special to begin with. This means that when the pointer is dereferenced it's the same as dereferencing an uninitialized pointer, which is *undefined behavior*, and will most likely cause a crash.

You probably mean to make it point to `input`?

Comment: ah yes that should be `double *in = (double *) input;` I've amended the question, but he problem persists though.

Comment: @Hemmer And the callstack looks the same?

Comment: Now the code runs without error, although the transform doesn't appear to be having any effect? I'll try and see I can make any progress and will report back. Thanks again for your help, I really appreciate it.